How to mount azure Share file to conatiners (in VM ) via docker compose?
I am using Docker compose to create 5 containers in VM  and i want to mount the azure files share to each container.
my docker-compose.yml file is as follow :
version: '3.8'

services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    user: root
    privileged: true
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs  
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sonarqube
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=username
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=username

  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    container_name: nexus
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    volumes:
      - "nexus_data:/nexus-data"

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/etc/prometheus
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus"
      - "--enable-feature=remote-write-receiver"


  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING=/etc/grafana/provisioning

    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana

    depends_on:
      - prometheus
volumes:
  jenkins_home
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share: jenkins_home
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key 
  sonarqube_data:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  sonarqube_logs:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_logs
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  sonarqube_extensions:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_extensions
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  nexus_data:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nexus-data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  prometheus_data:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: prometheus_data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  grafana_data:
    driver: azure
    driver_opts:
      share_name: grafana-data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key

And i did install the plugins from microsoft :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-volume-logging-drivers#using-your-own-volume-or-logging-driver
Yet i encounter this type of error the
enter image description here
even when i changed the docker compose file to create the azure share file as follow i changed the volume :
volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    driver: azure
  sonarqube_data:
    driver: azure
  sonarqube_logs:
    driver: azure
  sonarqube_extensions:
    driver: azure
  nexus_data:
    driver: azure
  prometheus_data:
    driver: azure
  grafana_data:
    driver: azure

it create the azure share file yet i got a permission error
enter image description here
ANY HELP Please i have a share file already created and i want to mount it to the containers via docker compose

For Azure File Share volumes, do not specify the share name directly in the Docker volume options. Instead, use the Azure File Share driver (azure) and provide the share name as part of the volume name.
Docker-compose.yml:*
version: '3.8'

services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    user: root
    privileged: true
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs  
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sonarqube
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=username
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=username

  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    container_name: nexus
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    volumes:
      - nexus_data:/nexus-data

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/etc/prometheus
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus"
      - "--enable-feature=remote-write-receiver"


  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING=/etc/grafana/provisioning
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: jenkins_home
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key 
  sonarqube_data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  sonarqube_logs:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_logs
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  sonarqube_extensions:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: sonarqube_extensions
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  nexus_data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nexus-data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  prometheus_data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: prometheus_data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key
  grafana_data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: grafana-data
      storage_account_name: storage
      storage_account_key: key

Here I have mounted an Azure File Share to each of these volumes.

To check the logs for a specific service, such as jenkins

# View logs for a service (e.g., jenkins)
docker-compose logs -f jenkins

# Print logs to a file and terminal simultaneously
docker-compose logs -f | tee compose-logs.txt



thank you for your response yet as i mentionned when i use share_name i got this error : metadata : not recognized volume driver option : share_name

Can you check the Azure File Share is properly installed and configured on your system. if not you can install by using this command docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions azurefile.

When i use that commande i got an error **Error response from daemon: error resolving plugin reference: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed **
so i install this plugin instead i found it in th Ms Documentaion [link]
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-volume-logging-drivers#using-your-own-volume-or-logging-driver)
docker plugin install --alias azure --grant-all-permissions docker4x/cloudstor:17.09.0-ce-azure1  CLOUD_PLATFORM=AZURE etc ...
